# Verify SQL Query completed MS Excel VBA

Tags: sql, vba, excel

In my workbook I have 3 SQL-database queries which are triggered using a

```vb
'Initiate datbase querying
ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
```

In my *DB_Connection* worksheet I added the following code to verify if the query ran successfully or failed (to be used in a log-sheet later on). If there are no more queries running, the macro continues with the next phase.

```vb
Private Sub QueryTable_AfterRefresh(Success As Boolean)

Dim Succeeded As Integer
Dim Failed As Integer

Succeeded = 0
Failed = 0

If Success Then
    Succeeded = Succeeded + 1
    Worksheets("DB_Connection").Range("L2").Value = Succeeded
Else
    Failed = Failed + 1
    Worksheets("DB_Connection").Range("M2").Value = Failed
End If

End Sub
```

However, the `QueryTable_AfterRefresh` is never called. I placed a stop to identify if it is being called or not.

Any suggestions?

Comment: @Parfait it's a handler, handling the `AfterRefresh` event of the `QueryTable` class: it's not "called", it's expected to be invoked by every `QueryTable` after it's refreshed, and OP is telling us they're refreshed using `ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll`. `ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll` *is* the code that should be "calling" this handler, but the event isn't fired, again per information that's already in the OP.

Comment: Are you handling errors in the code that calls `QueryTable_AfterRefresh`?  If so, it's possible you're erroring and jumping over this call.  It would be good to post the code that is supposed to be calling this sub.

Comment: How do I fire the event? The refreshall is in a standard module

Comment: If you navigate to that `QueryTable_AfterRefresh` procedure and look at the two dropdowns at the top of the code pane - does the right-hand one say `AfterRefresh` or `QueryTable_AfterRefresh`? Does the left-hand one say `(General)`, or does it say `QueryTable`? Do you have a `Private WithEvents QueryTable As QueryTable` declaration somewhere?

Comment: Lefthand dropdown (General) and righthand dropdown QueryTable_AfterRefresh

Comment: Then that's why it's not getting invoked. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just type out an event handler signature and expect it to work. If you navigate to that `QueryTable_AfterRefresh` procedure, you should notice the contents of the code pane drop-downs - the only way a handler procedure named `QueryTable_AfterRefresh` could exist and work, is if you have a `Private WithEvents QueryTable As QueryTable` declaration:

[image]

Notice the left-hand dropdown says `QueryTable` (the name of the `WithEvents` field) and the right-hand dropdown says `AfterRefresh` (the name of the event).

If what you have is this `(General)` on the left and `QueryTable_AfterRefresh` on the right:

[image]

...then what you're looking at is essentially dead code that nothing will ever invoke, at least not through `QueryTable` events.

Declare a module-level `WithEvents` variable, select it from the left-hand dropdown, then select the `AfterRefresh` event in the right-hand dropdown; the VBE will generate the correct method signature for *that event* on *that object*.

Then you need to `Set` that object reference before you do `ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll`. You could do that in the `Workbook_Open` handler, however with the field being `Private` you won't be able to access it from the `ThisWorkbook` module. One solution is to make it `Public`, a better solution is to expose a method to properly initialize it:

```vb
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents QueryTable As QueryTable

Public Sub Initialize()
    Set QueryTable = Me.QueryTables(1)
End Sub

Private Sub QueryTable_AfterRefresh(ByVal Success As Boolean)
    '...
End Sub
```

And then give that worksheet a compile-time *code name* (set its `(Name)` property in the *properties* toolwindow) and call that method from `Workbook_Open` in `ThisWorkbook` - for example if the sheet has `QuerySheet` for a *code name*, you can invoke it like this (note there's no need to dereference that object from the `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets` collection):

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    QuerySheet.Initialize
End Sub
```